# Video streaming after image processiong from server to web client

Tags: python, multithreading, video-streaming, flask-socketio, real-time-data

I am still a beginner and I am trying to develop a Home Surveillance application with facial recognition, where the main idea is to stream the image from the server to the web browser including additional data such as the name of the person detected/ unknown based on detection with OpenCV and other information from a database in case the person is recognized, such as sex, age, etc.
I did something that works, but I don't know how efficient it is, thus I would like some opinions.
I am using flask as the web server and socketio for transferring real-time data.
The actual app runs as follows: I have a function that starts at the beginning of a thread, `imageProcessing()`, which takes the frames from the camera and does all the image processing (face detection and recognition), and stores the frame and persons detected in one global variable, respectively array with persons recognized/ unknown. Next, the web server app begins and after the connection is established between the web client and web server, the frame and array of persons are sent along with additional information via web sockets to the web client. The delay is less than a second. So everything is running on the same app. So the questions here are:

1. Is it efficient to have a thread that does image processing running inside the server app?
2. Is it efficient and secure to use the global variable such that the function `imageProcessing()` is storing the image from camera and then this global variable at the same time is used by the `socket.emit()` which sends the frame to web client?

Here is part of the code of the main app. The function is irrelevant since just stores a result to a global variable and that's why I did not place it here.

````
```
import camera #this is a file containg the imageProcessing function and frame global variable
cameraThread = threading.Thread(target = camera.imageProcessing)
cameraThread.start()
 

eventlet.monkey_patch()
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, async_mode='eventlet')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/web')
def connect_web():
    print('[INFO] Web client connected: {}'.format(request.sid))

@socketio.on('message', namespace='/web')
def handle(msg):
    while True:
        message = {'image': camera.encode_image(camera.frame),'person': camera.person}
        time.sleep(0.1)
        socketio.emit('stream_response', message, namespace='/web', broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/local')
def disconnect_web():
    print('[INFO] Web client disconnected: {}'.format(request.sid))


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
````

Initially I tried to make a separate client where the image was taken from cameras and processed, then sent the result via web sockets to the web server and then again to the web client via web sockets, but when doing so, I had a delay of ~15 seconds.. I suppose this approach of having the web server independent from image processing app shall be better in theory from different reasons, but I do not know why I have such a delay..

3. Shall I still keep an independence between image processing client -> web server -> web client? If so then any suggestion for using another alternative/ technology since I have such a delay for this scenario using socket.io?
4. How would you develop such an app from an architecture design point of view? E.g Would you use WebSockets for streaming video or some other technology? Would you place image processing into a separate client/ app and transfer the result to the web server or all processing on the same server?

Comment: I did a project last weekend for a hackathon that involved OpenCV and real time image processing. While I can't comment much on your webapp's implementation, I know that I had image processing running in one process on its own CPU core and email server functionality on another core. If you want to get it working as you mentioned in the last scenario with the 15sec delay, try Python's multiprocessing library. This resulted in a huge speedup for my project. The delay is strange though, and I'll leave that up to more experienced users to answer.